Source for Zohar reference
What is the source for this:
Rabbi Dostai asked Rabbi Eliezer Hagadol. He said to him: Rabbi, help me understand the great secret of this verse, ‘The continual burnt-offering that was done at Mount Sinai for a satisfying aroma, an offering of fire to God.’ He said to him: My son, I swear, you have just said something to me that you are not suitable to understand, and no person has ever asked this of me, except for Akiva my student.”
In an article at https://www.lss.org/beitmorasha?post_id=65496 it says it's from Zohar Bereishit 12,2 but it doesn't seem to be from there.

They left out one word of the reference. It's supposed to be Zohar Chadash, Bereishis 12b, specifically the section called Midrash Hane'elam.
You can see it here, starting 13 lines from the bottom in the left-hand column. (Wikitext has it too, but mislabeled as 11b; and Sefaria has it but without the pagination at all.)
